# How to redirect to a different page when urlparameter.optional id is passed in the url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a sample ASP.Net MVC e-commerce application as a beginner as part of an assignment and have populated a grid of products with an image, product name and price given. On clicking on the image, I want the user to be redirected to the product detail page which will have a detailed description of the product along with other options such as add to cart and select quantity. To do this, I am thinking of passing the corresponding productID to the URL parameters. Is it possible to do this using the same controller and returning a different view?

For example -

> localhost/home/products

will give a view of all the products

whereas

> locahost/home/products/p001

will give the view with the detailed product description of the product with the ID p001 in the backend database. What I'm struggling to figure out is this - how do I display a different page when ID is passed? i.e. a dynamic page view?

Comment: Yes (you can just check if the parameter is `null`), but typically you would have separate controller methods (and the url would be `products/details/p001`). Why do you want to have just one method?

Comment: Well, since i have a Urlparameter.optional i wanted to utilize it in the HomeController. So is it possible to be still able to do that?

Comment: Yes - but it makes no sense.

Comment: I ultimately did it by adding a new controller and defining details as a method in the same. Thanks for the advice! :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Please refer below sample code
> ```

```
public ActionResult products(string Id)
    {
      if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id))
       {
          return View("FirstView");
       }
       else
       {
         return View("ProductDetailsView");
       }
    }
```